# Which view is opened first? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

I'm wondering where can I set which of my views will be opened first when I run my application? For example I have a `Login` folder that contains `Login.cshtml` view and I would like to show that view when my application is started?

Here is my RouteConfig (RIGHT NOW REGISTER PAGE IS OPENING IN MY PROJECT AND I COULDN'T FIND ANYTHING RELATED TO REGISTER FILE HERE, SO THAT'S REASON WHY I'M CONFUSED, WHERE THIS IS SET TO OPEN REGISTER VIEW WHEN MY MVC APP IS RUNNED) file :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

As you can see there is written `HomeController` and action method `Index`, so here is Home controller:

```
 [BaseAuthorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Again, here is nothing related to register view.. :(

How can I do it? Where to look if I want to set page/view that will be displayed when application is runned?

Probably this logic is written in `BaseAuthorize` I will figure it out soon, but I'm wondering what is anyway right way to do this?
Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Check the route configuration (RouteConfig.cs) it has a default controller and action set. You can change it to login action method

Comment: @Shyju What is confusing me here is next: When I start my project Register page is opened instead of Login page, and I checked previously RouteConfig.cs where I couldn't find anything related to register page, acctually routeconfig.cs looks like this (CHECK for edit please).

Comment: Where is this BaseAuthorize coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your default route, i. e. the page that will be opened when you access http://localhost, is the `HomeController` `Index` view, as per your route configuration.
Now, your controller is annotated with `BaseAuthorize`, which means the access to `Home/Index` requires authentication. If the request is not authenticated, then the it will be redirected to another page, which is probably the page you are getting.
There are two way to set your default page: you can change the route config to point to another controller/action, or you can change the default url to be whatever you want. You can set your project url via right click on your project > properties > web > project url.